# Retrieve previously selected chosen dropdown subject value(s)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm having a problem with the coding because I cannot get the chosen dropdown menu multi-select Version 1.4.2 to retrieve the previous selected subject value(s) from the dropdown menu when I click it again to activate it.

I'm using two different tables with one field name for each one, so I'm trying to match the t_subjects field name(s) in the member table with the name field name in the category table and if there is a match, that subjects field name will result in `<option value='subject_name' selected >subject_name</option>` and where there is no match it will be `<option value='subject_name'>subject_name</option>`

[This is what I'm trying to get to happen for those subjects that match when I click it anytime after the first post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLIJT.png)

There are forty-two subjects that are dynamically loaded in a chosen multi-select dd menu option.

I have no problem with posting the subject(s) names to the database using the implode method.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$subjects = implode(',', $_POST['subjects']);
```

But, if I open the page again to make another post with the subjects field name blank, I get an error that says:

```
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in...
```

So, you can see why I need to have the previous subject(s) values selected when I activate it again. Here is the code for the chosen dd menu.

```
<tr>
<td width="32%">Subjects:</td>
<td width="68%">

<input type="radio" name="utype" id="sutype" value="s" />Subject(s)


    <div id="studspan" style="display:none;">
    <strong style="vertical-align:top;">Select Subject(s) :</strong>

    <select name="subjects" id="subjects" data-placeholder="Select Subject(s)" style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select">

    <?php
    $cat_sele = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
    while ($cat_row=mysql_fetch_array($cat_sele)) {
    if($_POST['subjects'] == $cat_row['name']) $s = " selected"; else $s = "";
    echo "<option value='{$cat_row['name']}'$s>{$cat_row['name']}</option>";
    }
    ?>

    </select>

    </div>
```

The problem seems to be in this part of the code: `if($_POST['subjects'] == $cat_row['name'])`, because when I replace `$_POST['subjects']` with `'Accounting'` to check it, it will show that Accounting has been selected when I activate it again, but if I add another subject name, it will show all of the subjects as selected. I even tried `if($_POST['t_subjects'] == $cat_row['name'])` as well as `("SELECT name FROM category")`, but they didn't work either. So any help to help this teacher make it work will be very appreciative.

I have also included other parts of the code that are involved in the process too.

```
elseif($_SESSION['user_type']=="m")
    {
    $getuser_sele = "select * from member where member_id = '".$_SESSION['ses_id']."'";
    $getuser_qry = mysql_query($getuser_sele);
    $getuser_row = mysql_fetch_array($getuser_qry);
    $subjects = stripslashes($getuser_row['t_subjects']);
```

=============================================================

```
elseif($subjects=="" && $_SESSION['user_type']=="m")
    {
    $error="Please Enter Preferred Subjects";
    }
```

=============================================================

```
elseif($_SESSION['user_type']=="m")
    {
    $qr=mysql_query("update member set
    t_subjects='".addslashes($subjects)."',
```

=============================================================

```
<body onload="$('.chosen-select').show();
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();">
```

=============================================================

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#sutype").click(function () {

      $("#studspan").show(1000);
      $('.chosen-select').chosen('destroy');
      $('.chosen-select').show();
      $('.chosen-select').chosen();

    });

</script>

<script src="js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

=============================================================

Update:

Tristan, it works but it shows all of the subject names as selected and de-seleted in the choice list, which is not what I want to happen. I also got the following error in the source code for each of the subject names. I'm just showing the first one below.

```
<b>Warning</b>: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in <b>/home/.../.../edit.php</b> on line <b>2784</b><br /> <option value='Accounting' selected>Accounting</option><br />
```

I think the problem is how the table/fields are setup in the dbase.

Here is what should happen based upon the first row of the t_subjects. If I log in as member 1 and open the chosen dd menu, Accounting,Athletics,Art from row one of t_subjects should be selected while the rest of the subject list would be non selected in the chosen dd menu. This would happen for each member's row t_subjects they have listed when they initially posted them the first time.

[all images to show what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VSdv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<select name="subjects" ... multiple>` will only send post data for one selection. You need to use `<select name="subjects[]" ... multiple>` to send all selected options in the post data.

Then `$_POST['subjects']` will be an array so you will need to search the array for the category name.

```
$cat_sele = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
while ($cat_row=mysql_fetch_array($cat_sele)) {
    if(array_search($cat_row['name'], $_POST['subjects']) !== false) $s = " selected"; else $s = "";
    echo "<option value='{$cat_row['name']}'$s>{$cat_row['name']}</option>";
}
```

Comment: Tristan, I updated the question because I think the problem is how the two dbase tables are setup.